# binance.exceptions.BinanceAPIException: APIError(code=-1013): Filter failure: LOT_SIZE || binance api || Python

Tags: api, binance

I have a problem with Binance API when placing a market order using the `order_market_buy method`.

```
def order_market_buy(symbol, quantity):
    client.order_market_buy(symbol=symbol, quantity=quantity, recvWindow=50000)

order_market_buy('BNBBTC', 0.0001)
```

When you run this code, the following error occurs.

> BTC on the wallet account is enough to carry out a transaction.

What could be the cause of the error?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `BNBBTC` pair means you want to buy `BNB` using `BTC`. That error suggests that you don't have enough `BTC` in your Binance account. Also, the minimum transaction size is $10 so with the current price of `BNB` you might have to buy closer to .017 of it.